# How do I grab a single image and put it in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, image, html, base64, local-storage

How is it done, of course without external libraries, in regular HTML with JavaScript? This seems like it should be a simple one-liner.

I'd like to just do:

```
<script>
localStorage.image=src("http://"+randomflikrimage+".jpg")
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try storing base64 data, use canvas. Check this: [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)